# Global link to manually installed Firefox

Tags: firefox, shortcuts, debian-jessie

I just uninstalled Iceweasal in Debian Jessie and extracted the copy of Firefox that I downloaded to `usr/local/`. It is now in that folder and I can run it by clicking on the app in the folder, but how can I create a global link that will show up in all the computer users accounts as well as the applications menu?

Comment: I don't know of an equivalent to the Windows **All Users** account in Linux. What I would do is create a launcher in a user account, then move it to a central place (in `/etc` say), and modify one of the log-on files to make sure it is copied to each user's desktop (`~/Desktop/`) and home directory tree (`~/.local/share/applications/`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a .desktop file to launch the firefox in application menu.

My firefox.desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Web Browser
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
GenericName=Web Browser
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Exec=firefox %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=firefox
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=NewWindow;NewPrivateWindow;

[Desktop Action NewWindow]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=firefox -private-window
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action NewPrivateWindow]
Name=Open a New Private Window
Exec=firefox -private-window
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

There are 3 Exec entries, just change them with your executable's location, like this:

Exec=firefox %u  ->   Exec=/usr/local/firefox/firefox %u

Exec=firefox -new-window  ->  Exec=/usr/local/firefox/firefox -new-window

Exec=firefox -private-window  ->  Exec=/usr/local/firefox/firefox -private-window

then copy this file to /usr/share/applications/   (requires root)

about .desktop files: https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en

If you launch firefox in terminal directly you should make a symbolic link in /usr/bin to your executable

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```